# Algorithm Photoshop uses to match colors on images

Tags: javascript, algorithm, colors, photoshop

I have asked [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/124538/how-to-normalize-the-colors-of-a-set-of-arbitrary-images-into-a-consistent-inst) question about "How to normalize the colors of a set of arbitrary images into a consistent, instagram-like filtered look".

> I have a thousand images let's say, of all different types, basically like what you would find on Wikipedia. They are all JPGs though. Some of them have a solid light or dark background with a figure on top (like a person on a black background, or an animal on a white background, or a green background, etc.). Some of them are like a scene of flowers and grasses and trees, so highly complicated color arrangement (i.e. not a simple solid color). Some of them already have a hint of a filter on them (whether it's "vintage" look or "cool temperature" or "warm" or high contrast HDR look).
>
> I'm wondering what my options are for making the overall design of a grid of images feel fully integrated into the surrounding Flat UI design of the website, and so the images have perhaps a hint of one of the accent colors or non-accent colors, and all the images have the same overall temperature/saturation/contrast/etc. Wondering if it's possible to do this.
>
> I am imagining I would figure out how to do this using a color library in JavaScript rather than going through each image manually and adjusting the sliders. I want it to be automatic somehow, if at all possible. That is, I somehow write some code that figures out a "baseline" style for the images, then compares each image to that style and adjusts it the appropriate amount to match. Wondering (a) if this is even possible, and (2) (if it's not too much to ask) if you could point me in the right direction on how to get started.
>
> In the end, all of the images would have the same color palette roughly, same overall filter effect look.

Wondering how photoshop does this. If not how they do it *exactly* (don't need to know the exact algorithm), wondering what a general algorithm is that can solve this in JavaScript. I don't really know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS filters. Give your images a class and select them by class.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

```
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.brightness {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.30);
  filter: brightness(0.30);
}

.contrast {
  -webkit-filter: contrast(180%);
  filter: contrast(180%);
}

.grayscale {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.huerotate {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}

.invert {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.opacity {
  -webkit-filter: opacity(50%);
  filter: opacity(50%);
}

.saturate {
  -webkit-filter: saturate(7);
  filter: saturate(7);
}

.sepia {
  -webkit-filter: sepia(100%);
  filter: sepia(100%);
}

.shadow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px green);
  filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px green);
}
.inverted{
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%); /* Safari */
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

Code snippet:

```css
.imgFilter {
  -webkit-filter: sepia(45%);
  filter: sepia(45%);

}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Oryctolagus_cuniculus_Tasmania_2.jpg/220px-Oryctolagus_cuniculus_Tasmania_2.jpg" />

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Oryctolagus_cuniculus_Tasmania_2.jpg/220px-Oryctolagus_cuniculus_Tasmania_2.jpg" class="imgFilter" />
```

Comment: Say the images to normalize are: [a](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Illustrations#/media/File:Adolphe_Millot_mollusques-pour_tous.jpg), [b](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:16th-century_illustrations#/media/File:Birds_of_Hindustan,_such_as_crows,_magpies,_and_cuckoos,_that_live_beside_water,_and_alligators.jpg), [c](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Macro_photography#/media/File:Can_You_Hear_Me_Now!!_(19204183003).jpg), [d](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Macro_photography#/media/File:The_Little_Things_in_Life_(26360912140).jpg).

Comment: I don't see in your example how two differently colored images can be normalized to the same output.

Comment: See this: https://codepen.io/stilllife00/pen/avXpgJ
You can see upon hover that they have the same colorization.